# Replacing exe icon with WiX

Tags: wix, icons

So we are OEM'ing our app, and we have multiple WiX projects referencing our app.

Now it's easy enough to switch out the ico used to create the shortcuts, control panel add/remove icon, etc... But is there a way to change the icon that is inside my applications exe?

Comment: What EXE are you referring to? Are you using WiX 3.6 with Burn to generate a setup.exe or are you talking about your own application's EXE that you are packaging with WiX?

Comment: My own applications, exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a WiX question, IMO.   Windows Program Executables ( PE ) files have embedded resources.  You would need to use a resource editor  to take your compiled EXE and replace icon.   Otherwise you'd have to recompile your EXE from source with a new icon.

Another possibility is your EXE is a very thin veneer that launches a DLL(s) where your real code is.  This way people can create different implementations of the EXE for branding purposes yet share common functionality.

I do something like that in the [Fireworks](http://fireworks.codeplex.com/) and [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com/) projects found on CodePlex.

Comment: yuck, I've got the app itself loading a different icon at runtime for the window/taskbar and all the shortcuts use the new icon.  I guess I'll just live with the exe having it's current icon (or strip it out entirely).